# Django: Is this bad practice?

Tags: python, html, django, http, styles

Here's the functionality that I'm looking for -- A user fills out a form on the default page, index.html. When it is submitted, I receive a POST request, whose contents I add to a database. Next, I want to load a new page whose content will be contingent on the information from the form.

This is my implementation -- I'm handling the POST request within my `index(request)` function. I originally returned a `HTTPResponseRedirect(navigation/route.html)`, but I later found after searching StackOverflow that it is not possible to both redirect and send the contents of the form. I'm working around this by returning `render(request, 'navigation/route.html', {'form': form})`.

I'm just concerned because it seems like `HTTPResponseRedirect` intentionally prevents the user from passing POST request data, meaning my attempt to bypass that structural restriction might be a bad idea.

Here is the relevant portion of my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # populate form with information from POST request
        form = TripForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # input into database
            trip_instance = Trip(**form.cleaned_data)
            trip_instance.save()

            # redirect
            return render(request, 'navigation/route.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        # either request is not POST or form did not pass validation checks
        form = TripForm
    return render(request, 'navigation/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: If the request method is `GET`, you need to pass the form instance in the context, not the class reference.

Comment: In general, if it works, and you understand it, it is not bad practice.  As for your particular implementation, I don't see anything wrong with it.  This question is very subjective though, so it might get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not HttpResponseRedirect that prevents this, it is the structure of HTTP itself; a 302 redirect tells the browser to request a new page, but does preserve the POST dictionary.

And that's not the reason why you shouldn't do what you're doing. As the documentation explains, you should always do an actual redirect after a successful POST, so that a browser refresh doesn't cause the form to be reposted.

The way to do what you want is to pass the trip ID in the URL you are redirecting to, and then query it back in that view. Alternatively, you could save the value in the session.